# In Pandas, how can I group by twice, on two different axes?

Tags: python, pandas

This works to group my data by 5-year chunks:

```
dg = df.groupby((df.index//5)*5).mean()['matches-ratio']
dg.plot()
```

and this works to group my data by gender (a column):

```
dg = df.groupby(['gender'])['matches-ratio']
dg.plot()
```

But I can't seem to group by both gender and 5-year chunks. I've tried things like `dg = df.groupby(['gender', (df.index//5)*5]).mean()['matches-ratio']`, but this gives weird results, where dates are grouped by gender (???) and 5-year groups, so the the x axis is labeled "gender, date." Chaining them, like this:

```
dg = df.groupby(['gender'])['matches-ratio']
dg = dg.groupby((df.index//5)*5).mean()
dg.plot()
```

gives `AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'groupby' of 'SeriesGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`. How can I group twice, on different axes? (date = x axis, 'matches-ratio' = y axis)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to followup your groupby with an unstack

```
(df.groupby(['gender', (df.index//5)*5])
   .mean()['matched-ratio']
   .unstack()
   .plot())
```

This will create a separate line for each gender.

Comment: I had to transpose it with `.transpose()` before plotting, and fill in NANs again, but it works!

Comment: You can control which level gets unstacked (moved from the MultiIndex to the columns) with `.unstack`. That way you avoid the transpose.